# c++ and oracle DB and linked lists, which data structures to use?

Tags: c++, oracle, algorithm

I am writing a program that receives data over time and I am looking for different patterns in the data.

I have to save data for different  processes that I create in the program for future calculations,
I want to save the data to an Oracle DB (that has some support for storing objects).

the information that I want to relate to a new process has the following structure:
list of logic expressions:

```
stage 1  ->(a*b*c)+(d*e)+..(can have more conditions)
stage 2  ->(f*a*c)+(a*b)+..
stage 3  ->(g*h*i)+(j*k)+..
```

each letter: a,b, c,d etc represent a logic function that has different parameters related to it, I need to save these parameters for future usage of each logic function.
the * represents logical AND
the + represents logical OR

The question is how to implement it?
I can create an object for each letter, e.g. for "a" (which can be a function or a condition that needs to be check etc) and save the data of this object to the oracle DB.

A numerator can be given to each process to identify it, however I am not sure how to identify each one of the logic functions (e.g. "a") because I need later to assemble the data from the database back to the original process that I am handling (example stage 1).

Regarding linked lists, not sure if to use them in my program to represent the structure of each logic in each stage   e.g.  a->b->c->(new OR expression)->d->e.  or maybe there is a better solution? I can also save this information as a string and try to do parsing later
e.g.  `string command="stage 1  ->(a*b*c)+(d*e)"`

in case that I will be using linked list, I am not sure how to save the structure of the lists to the database.

for the external structure, stage1,stage2, stage3.. etc not sure also if to use linked lists and how to save them to a database.
I would appreciate some advice on how to build it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's build this from the bottom up.  You want to refrain from writing your own linked list structures, if possible.

A stage consists of one or more products that are summed.

The products are pointers to functions or function objects, let's call them *functors*.

Each group of functions objects could be a `std::vector<function_object>`.  These group would have the results multiplied together; which can be handled in a loop.

A stage is one or more of the above vectors.  This can be expressed as:
`std::vector< std::vector<function_object> >`

You can add another *dimension* for the stages:
`std::vector< std::vector< std::vector<function_object> > >`

If you prefer to use linked list, replace `std::vector` with `std::list`.

**Edit 1: Function IDs not objects**
Most databases have a difficult time storing code for a function.  So, you'll have to use *function identifiers* instead.

A function identifier is a number associated with a function.  This association will be in your code and not in the data.  The easiest implementation is to use an array of function objects or pointers.  Use the function identifier as an index into the array, the retrieve the functor.

A more robust method is to use a table of `<function_id, functor>`.  This structure allows for the records to be in any order, and the records can be deleted without damaging the code.  With the vector, slots must never be removed.

```
struct Table_Entry
{
  unsigned int     function_id;
  Function_Pointer p_function;
  const char *     function_name;
};

Table Entry  function_associations[] =
{
  {5, logic_function_1, "Logic Function 1"},
  //...
};
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, thank you for the answer, I want to build it in a way that every process would be fully backup to a database (in case there is a crash or in case that I want to re use a process). how to do it?

Comment: Hi Thomas, if I understand correctly, what you are suggesting can be also achieved using STL MAP("logic_function_1", pointer to function 1), MAP("logic_function_2", pointer to function 2) etc, where 1,2 are numerators of objects in the database or names. however what I don´t understand is how to save the structure of the process to a DB, e.g.  "stage 1  ->(a*b*c)+(d*e)" ,assuming "a".."e" are already stored in the DB with names or numerators that I know how to access them, thanks

Comment: I can save the expression "stage 1 ->(a*b*c)+(d*e)" in a DB as a list of numbers,2(2 sums),3(3 product in the first expression),2,10001(first numerator to point to "a"),..,1005 but I am not sure its the best way to do it.

Comment: How else can you save the functions?

Comment: This is the best idea I have, I just wanted to ask if there is a better solution, thanks for the answer.